# clearRect isnt clearing canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

im developing a game as a coding exercise  and ive come across a bug that i cant find when ever i press the selected button it does not remove the shape and redraw anotheer one it for some reason just keeps the shape on the page and draws a new shae i need it to delete the old shape and redraw a new shape [this is how the game should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc7rI.gif)
   enter code here

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
 
  function clear(ctx, width, height) {

  }

  function drawRandomShape(width, height) {
    //ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
   // var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)

    var number = 30;
    var countdown = setInterval(function(){
      timerSpan.innerHTML = number--;
      //console.log(number)
      if(number == 0 - 1){
        clearInterval(countdown);
      }
    },1000);
    function randomShape(){
      var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      //ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
     // if(number > 0){
        if(randomNum >= 0 && randomNum <= 2){
      //    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var triangle = ctx.beginPath();
          triangle += ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
          triangle += ctx.lineTo(90, 90);
          triangle += ctx.lineTo(0, 90);
          triangle += ctx.closePath();
          triangle += ctx.fillStyle = "red";
          triangle += ctx.fill();

          document.addEventListener('keyup', function shape(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 37){        
              triangle += ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
              document.removeEventListener('keyup', shape);
              randomShape();
            }
          });
        }else if(randomNum > 2 && randomNum <= 4){
        //  ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);   
          var blackTriangle = ctx.fillStyle = "black";
          blackTriangle += ctx.beginPath();
          blackTriangle += ctx.moveTo(0,0);
          blackTriangle += ctx.lineTo(90, 90);
          blackTriangle += ctx.lineTo(0, 90);
          blackTriangle += ctx.fill();

          document.addEventListener('keyup', function shape(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 38){
              blackTriangle += ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
              document.removeEventListener('keyup', shape);
              randomShape();
            }
          });
        }else if(randomNum >= 4 && randomNum <= 6){
          //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var redSquare = ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
          redSquare += ctx.rect(200, 100, 90, 90)
          redSquare += ctx.fill();
          document.addEventListener('keyup', function shape(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 39){
              redSquare += ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
              randomShape()
            }
          });
          
        }else if(randomNum > 6 && randomNum < 10){
          //ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var whiteSquare = ctx.rect(50,70,90,90);
          whiteSquare += ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
          whiteSquare += ctx.fill();

          document.addEventListener('keyup', function shape(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 40){
              whiteSquare += ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
              document.removeEventListener('keyup', shape);
              randomShape();
            }
          });
        }
        console.log(randomNum)
      //};
    }
    randomShape();
  }
  //}, 1000);
  function drawGameStartText(width, height ,score) {
    width = 170;
    height = 350;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'White';
    ctx.font = '30px Verdana'
    ctx.fillText('Press space bar to start a new game' , width , height);
  }

  function restartGame(ctx, width, height){

  }

      var canvas = document.getElementById("shapes-game"),
      height = canvas.scrollHeight,
      width = canvas.scrollWidth,
      gameOn = false,
      expectedKey = undefined,
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      // white triangle = up, red square = down,
      // red triangle = left, white square = right
      expectedKeysMap = {white0: 38, red1: 40, red0: 37, white1: 39};
      timerSpan = document.getElementById("time-remaining");

      scoreSpan = document.getElementById("score-val"),
      seconds = 3;
     // intervalId;
  document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
      drawRandomShape();
    }
  });
  drawGameStartText()
})
```

```css
body {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#shapes-game {
  border: 4px solid grey;
  background-color: black;
}

.canvas-container {
  padding: 10px;
}
.canvas-container, #shapes-game {
  height: 750px;
  width: 800px;
}

.scores {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.legend {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.legend-contents {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.triangle-bottomleft-red {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}

.triangle-bottomleft-black {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 54px solid black;
  border-right: 58px solid transparent;
}

.triangle-inner-white {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 50px solid white;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}

.triangle-left {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 23px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 23px solid transparent;
    border-right: 23px solid red;
}

.inner-triangle {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: 2px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid blue;
}

.red-square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.white-square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Shapes!!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-10 canvas-container">
      <canvas id="shapes-game" height="750" width="800"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 scores">
      <h1>Score</h1>
      <h3><span id="score-val">0</span></h3>
      <h1>Timer</h1>
      <h3><span id="time-remaining">30</span></h3>
      <div class="legend">
        <h1>Legend</h1>
        <div class="legend-contents">
          <div class="triangle-bottomleft-red">
          </div>
          <h4>Left</h4>
          <div class="white-square">
          </div>
          <h4>Right</h4>
          <div class="triangle-bottomleft-black">
            <div class="triangle-inner-white"></div>
          </div>
          <h4>Up</h4>
          <div class="red-square">
          </div>
          <h4>Down</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you think the line `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)` does?  What do you think it returns?  The way you have it written, it is going to clear the whole canvas.

Comment: well how would i be able to just clear the shapes?

Comment: i see a lot of commented out `clearRect` is that places where you tried putting it and it didn't work?

Comment: yeah i tried putting it in different places nothing worked so i came here

Comment: You don't.  You redraw everything every frame.  You can try to come up with some culling optimizations to try and cut down how much you have to redraw every frame, but that is way beyond the scope of this question.  The easiest way to do this is to just redraw your shapes.  Once things are drawn to the canvas, they aren't things anymore; they are just a big array of rgba values.  There is no context of individual objects as far as the canvas is concerned.

Comment: its not an animation though sorry if i got it wrong but im very new to canvas

Comment: zero298 is right ! If you absolutely want to clear a part of the canvas just use clearRect over the shape !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a zillion things wrong with your code.

First of why are you doing

> ```
>    var blackTriangle = ctx.fillStyle = "black";
>    blackTriangle += ctx.beginPath();
> ```

As it does absolutely nothing.

Create one key handler and handle everything in that rather than

> ```
>   document.addEventListener('keyup', function shape(e){
>     if(e.keyCode == 39){
>       redSquare += ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
>       randomShape()
>     }
>   });
> ```

You are just creating a pile of key handlers.

If you want to track shapes you are drawing create an array for each shape

```
  const shapes = {
    whiteSquares : [],
    redSquares : [],
    whiteTriangle : [],
    redTriangle: [],  
  };
```

then when you add the shape add it to the appropriate array

```
    if(randomNum <= 2){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(90, 90);
      ctx.lineTo(0, 90);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx.fill();
      shapes.redTriangle.push([0,0]); // store the top left of the triangle
    }
```

Then you can clear it in the key handler

```
  var gameStarted = false;
  const keyNames = {
    space : 32,
    left : 37;
    up : 38,
    right : 39,
    down : 40,
  }
  // only one key handler needed.
  document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    if(gameStarted === false && e.keyCode === keyNames.space) { 
      gameStarted = true;
      drawRandomShape();
    }else if(e.keyCode === keyNames.left) { 
      if(shapes.redTriangle.length > 0){
        var pos = shapes.redTriangle.shift(); // remove the bottom item in the array
        ctx.clearRect(pos[0],pos[1],90,90); // clear that position
        randomShape();  // create anothe shape.          
      }    
    }else if(e.keyCode === keyNames.right) { 
      if(shapes.whiteSquares.length > 0){
        // same as above
      }    
    }else if(e.keyCode === keyNames.up) { 
      if(shapes.whiteTriangle.length > 0){
        // same as above
      }
    }else if(e.keyCode === keyNames.down) { 
      if(shapes.redSquares.length > 0){
        // same as above
      }
    }
  }
```

Dont over complicate conditional statements.

You have

> ```
>     var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
>
>     if(randomNum >= 0 && randomNum <= 2){
>         // do stuff
>     }else if(randomNum > 2 && randomNum <= 4){
>         // do stuff
>     }else if(randomNum >= 4 && randomNum <= 6){
>         // do stuff
>     }else if(randomNum > 6 && randomNum < 10){
>         // do stuff
>     }
> ```

is the same as

```
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

    if (randomNum <= 2) { 
        // do stuff
    } else if(randomNum <= 4) { 
        // do stuff
    } else if(randomNum <= 6) { 
        // do stuff
    } else { 
        // do stuff
    }
```